# Oracle SQL: Retrieving a record more than once

Tags: sql, oracle, select, duplicates

I'm using Oracle 11 and would like to be able to retrieve a record more than one in a query, which would be a good convenience saving for the next part of my code.

Let's consider this SQL statement:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM PEOPLE WHERE NAME IN ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice');
```

It returns this data:

```
| 1 | Alice | 
| 2 | Bob   |
```

What I'd really like to do is to un-uniquify that list and return the records with duplicates, in the order given. So the above statement would be:

```
| 1 | Alice | 
| 2 | Bob   |
| 1 | Alice |
```

I appreciate that Oracle is optimized to remove repetition like this, and I could re-use the data afterwards, keep it in a store object and retrieve by name etc. I was just wondering if there was a way to make this happen on the database itself.

Comment: If you only have those three names, you could do three different selects and a union all. Union all does not remove duplicates.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri That's an interesting solution. Unfortunately I'll need to scale it up to a larger number of records.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan `select distinct` still returns two records. Because the rows are identical.

Comment: Use a subquery rather than an `IN` and set up a `JOIN`. If you want three rows in the output, there'll have to be three rows in the input somewhere.

Comment: excuse me, you want repetition, OK, for this aim @RigertaDemiri's suggestion is nice.

Comment: How many records in your Table 2 or 3. If there are record 3 records. Your query output should be 3 records. Because you are not applying distinct anywhere

Comment: @DeepakKumar The table, in this example, is 2 records long. It could be longer, but I'm still selecting by a unique value.

Comment: OK, if those two rows are the same record, I'm fairly confident using a union as @RigertaDemiri suggested is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle has a couple of handy built-in functions that return lists of arguments that you can then transform to a table and join on it. In your case, `odcivarchar2list` can be used to return a list of `varchar2`s:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   TABLE(sys.odcivarchar2list('Alice', 'Bob', 'Alice')) dups
JOIN   people p ON p.name = dups.column_value*
```

Answer (score 3):

query below for record with duplicate

```
select x.id,x.name from (
  select a.id,a.name from people a where a.name in ('Alice')
  union all
  select a.id,a.name from people a where a.name in ('Bob')
  union all
  select a.id,a.name from people a where a.name in ('Alice')
) x
```

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but just wanted to add you can use a traditional table expression:

```
select p.id, p.name
  from (
    select 'Alice' as name from dual
    union all select 'Bob' from dual
    union all select 'Alice' from dual
  ) searched s
  join people p on p.name = s.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another idea:

```
WITH cteNumbers as (SELECT LEVEL AS N
                      FROM DUAL
                      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2),
     PEOPLE AS (SELECT 'Bob' AS NAME, 111 AS EMPID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Carol' AS NAME, 222 AS EMPID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Ted' AS NAME, 333 AS EMPID FROM DUAL UNION ALL
                SELECT 'Alice' AS NAME, 444 AS EMPID FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM PEOPLE p
  CROSS JOIN cteNumbers
  WHERE 1 = CASE
              WHEN NAME = 'Alice' THEN 1
              WHEN NAME = 'Bob' AND N = 1 THEN 1
              WHEN NAME = 'Ted' AND N < 4 THEN 1
              WHEN NAME = 'Carol' AND N = 3 THEN 1
              ELSE 0
            END
  ORDER BY NAME, N
```

Basically, use cteNumbers to generate a list of number (in this case, from 1 to 2 - adjust the `CONNECT BY LEVEL` condition to control how many numbers are generated), then use the `CASE` expression in the `WHERE` clause to control the circumstances under which a particular record's repetitions are selected.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55714/22)